# How to set title for video embed field

Tags: 8, files

I've a video embed field, where I've a youtube video link, I've printed the same on the twig.

But it seems not to have the title for the iframe. How can I add one for iframe in drupal 8.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Paragraphs](https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs) and then add Title and Video Embed Field in the paragraph type, this is something like Field Collection in D7.

Video about [How to use paragraphs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fy9s01T30uo).